# Bind Window.Effect to ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, uielement

I wonder how would it be possible to bind `Window.Effect` to `ViewModel` so that it could be the `ViewModel` controlling how the window looks like.

I'm aware that we can bind properties *one-by-one* such as following; however, this is not really binding `Effect` rather is binding settings to the `Effect` which is not of my interest.

```
<Window.Effect>
     <BlurEffect Radius="{Binding UIElementEffect.Radius}" />
</Window.Effect>
```

Comment: There's some really interesting chat about this kind of thing here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896612/are-wpf-related-properties-inside-a-viewmodel-a-violation-of-mvvm-best-practices . The gist of it is that it's probably a bad idea to put an actual UI object in your ViewModel, but you could use an abstraction of one and run it through a converter to populate your Effect's properties.

Comment: You can do whatever you want, but if you're doing UI tasks in your VM that's not MVVM.

Comment: @Will Disagree. VM is a model of view (model of window or model of other UI element), it's supposed to "do UI tasks".

Comment: @roman There's no need to disagree.  The pattern is well defined and well documented. I'd suggest you go try finding support for your claim, as you can only benefit from such research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just bind like this:

```
<Window
    ...
    Effect ="{Binding WindowEffect}">
```

?

As for "if it's a bad idea to put WPF/UI-specific object into ViewModel" and other "best-practices" and patterns I personally have a rule: I ask myself:
- What real problem will I get if I violate this best-practice (btw, are best-practices always best and best for everyone? ;) )? By real I mean real - not theoretical problems that someone has written in a book or some forum. Will these problems apply for my specific project? What is the chance this problem will really happen? Do disadvantages (problems that may actually never arise) outweigh the advantages of violating the "best-practice" (like simplicity, comfort of working with the code, etc.)?
I am not suggesting to violate best-practices, I am suggesting not to follow them blindly.